# Im trying to use indexof and substring to get string from file whats wrong in the code?

Tags: c#

```
 private void test()
 {
   int index = 0;
   int length = 0;

   while (true)
   {
     index = f.IndexOf("Text", index + 1);
     if (index == -1)
     {
       break;
     }
     int t = f.IndexOf("<", index);
     int e = f.IndexOf("/", t);
     string g = f.Substring(index , f.Length - t);

   }
 }
```

The text file im trying to get the string out from is content:

```
daniel<Text>THISISOUTisthere</Text>
<Text>hellobye</Text>
<Text>danielTHISishereandnotthere</Text>
danie <Text> is THIS here and not THERE</Text>
```

In the end i want that g will contain each time the text between the tags Text and the tag Text in the end i cant write here the symbole lower then and upper then but i want to get only the text between this two tags according to to my code. using:

```
<Text> and </Text> tags
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cant you just use the XmlTextReader class which will automatically parse and break this stuff up for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you *really* want to do it this way and not use `XmlTextReader`, which is fine - sometimes it's fun to roll your own solution, you might try something like this.  I didn't test it but it's probably close, if I understand what you want to do:

```
string startTag = "<Text>";
string endTag = "</Text>";
int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
index = 0;
while (true)
{
   index = f.IndexOf(startTag, index);
   if (index == -1) 
   {
      break; 
   }
   // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag
   int start = index + startTagWidth;
   index = f.IndexOf(endTag, start+1);
   if (index == -1)
   {
      break; 
   }
   // found the endTag
   string g = f.SubString(start, index - start)
}
```

Comment: Certainly an opportunity to have an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` thrown if `start+1` ends up past the end of the string, but otherwise,  it might accomplish what you want.

Comment: this is not the best prectice to show how to solve this problrm

Comment: @Artur - my point wasn't to create the "best practice" solution to this problem - there are much better ways, but what the OP asked was "what's wrong in the code?" - the code he wrote,  not "write the optimal solution", which I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I lot of the XML classes probably wouldn't be happy parsing this anyway since it's not a valid  XML fragment.

You could also use a regular expression such as:

```
Regex r = new Regex("<Text>(.*?)</Text>");
var matches = r.Matches(f);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    sb.Append(match.Groups[1]);

}
var g = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: That regex should be `<Text>(.*?)</Text>` you need it to be non greedy, albeit the OP doesn't make it clear whether <Text></Text> would appear twice on a line.

Comment: @Bob Vale Good spotting. Cheers for that.